# Squid outgoing address configuration with 2 interfaces

Tags: networking, linux-networking, squid, local-area-network

I'm trying to forward the traffic from one network (net1) to another network (network2) via a squid proxy which has 2 interfaces (eth1 and eth0) using the `tcp_outgoing_address` option.

My network is as follows:

```
192.168.122.0/24(net2) -----eth1[Squid server]eth0----- 192.168.124.0/24 (net1)
```

The IP addresses of the squid server:

- 192.168.122.5 (eth1)
- 192.168.124.10 (eth0)

My goal is that a web server in the net1 (192.168.122.0) sees the request as it came from 192.168.122.5 (the eth1 of squid server)

I have tried to achieve it but seems not working. Here is my squid config:

```
##Creating the acls
acl net_1 src 192.168.122.0/24
acl net_2 src 192.168.124.0/24

##INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow all
tcp_outgoing_address 192.168.124.10 net_1
tcp_outgoing_address 192.168.122.5 net_2

##And finally deny all other access to this proxy

##http_access deny all

##Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 192.168.124.10:3128
http_port 192.168.122.5:4445
```